# How do I merge `git rm` commits back into master?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

So part of the work I've been doing on a branch of a Git repository has involved removing unused files. eg.

```
git rm "unused-file.txt"
git commit -m "clean up things"
```

How can I best merge changes like this (along with my other normal commits on existing files) back into master? If I:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_branch
```

Git's auto-merge just leaves the files I deleted on my branch in place, as they don't conflict with the ones still there on master.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, Git _should_ remove those files as part of the merge automatically. To be clear: You `git rm` a file on `my_branch`, then commit on `my_branch`, then checkout `master`, then merge `my_branch` into `master`. Are you sure that the file removal was successfully committed on `my_branch`?

Comment: Do you have a clean working tree before merging? If not, that could be causing the issue. In my experience, with a clean working tree this always works fine. But things get wonky with a dirty working tree.

Comment: Ha turns out I was being an idiot and this was actually the behaviour you describe @Chris ! Thanks all for the help anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git's auto-merge does it. I'm an idiot. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think add the deleted file in your working directory to Index after deleting which will show that the file is deleted in the Index and update while merging.

```
    git checkout my_branch
    git rm "unused-file.txt" 
    git status
    git add unused-file.txt || git add .
    git commit -m "Clean up things" 
    git checkout master 
    git merge my_branch
```

I think this is want you are looking for. Let me know if this works

Comment: Turns out I was being an idiot and it was actually removing things as it should.... Oh dear! Thanks very much for the response anyway :-)